# Copying records from one database to another using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We use a different database for each of our "projects" and are looking to use Entity Framework models to copy table records from one database to another to reduce the massive data entry that would be required in some circumstances.

Because we use a variety and a growing number of databases, we use the same set of models and context class. We just supply a different database name to the context.

Because we first set the unit of work for the source project, grab the data, then set the unit of work for the destination project, and use a `CopyRange()` method to simply take the values from the source model records and add a new record using those values. (note: The `CopyRange()` method seems to work well in a number of situations, so it's not shown. Let me know if you think I should add it, however.) Because EF tracks the models, this approach has proven to be problematic

That said, the example below shows the only way that we've gotten this to work. First we must grab the model from the source db using `AsNoTracking()`, then we must return the value to an `IEnumerable` using `ToList()`. All these conditions seem to be necessary, or an error will be thrown when trying to add the source values to the destination database.

Essentially, as you can see, we are trying to turn the source models into untracked, dumb data transfer objects so that they don't get tangled with the destination database context. Using `AsNoTracking()` and using `IEnumerable()` instead of `IQueryable()` seems to make sense to achieve this goal, though it's not exactly clear why `ToList()` is needed to avoid an error.

The final approach we have here was discovered through testing. We want to verify whether this is a problematic approach or if there is something more stable/standard that we should be doing. Thanks in advance.

Repository class where the data is retrieved from the source database:

```
internal class SomeTableRepository : Repository<SomeTable>
{
        ...
        public IQueryable<AnotherTable> GetAllNoTracking()
        {
            return DbContext.SomeTables.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.Deleted == false);
        }
}
```

From the client class...

```
            //Retrieve source entities
            IEnumerable<SomeTable> someTables;

            //Set source Db name and start unit of work.
            DAL.Support.Keys.DbCatalogName = _SourceDbName;
            using (UnitOfWork uOWSource = new(new __DbContext()))
            {
                someTables = uOWSource.SomeTables.GetAllNoTracking().ToList();
            }

            //Set destination Db name and start unit of work.
            DAL.Support.Keys.DbCatalogName = _DestinationDbName;
            using (UnitOfWork uOWDest = new(new __DbContext()))
            {
                //First, clear table
                someTables = uOWDest.SomeTables.RemoveAll().ToList();
                
                //Copy values from the source records into new records that are added to the destination Db
                uOWDest.SomeTables.CopyRange(someTables);
            }
```

Comment: While you *can* use Entity Framework to copy across tables, have you considered SSIS packages for ETL?

Comment: @CameronTinker, we have not looked into that. We're hoping to use out-of-the-box EF.

Comment: If you need to copy rows in code, it might be best to use something like plain ADO.NET or Dapper and bypass EF, unless you need the entities tracked as part of the copy. SSIS is a great option for ETL if you have access to SQL Agent on your SQL Server instance(s).

Comment: I understand there are other approaches. This is a simple utility, and would prefer to stay generally with the approach described, barring any potential issues with it.

Comment: Entity Framework just isn't built for and intended for large-scale bulk data copying - that's the ETL domain --> use the most appropriate tool for the job at hand

Comment: +100 for using SSIS, or heck if it's a one-off & not huge, generated scripts. EF would be a very poor choice for trying to build a capability like this as it is intended to serve as a translation layer between application logic and data state. Loading every row from one DbContext into an entity just to detach and re-attach to another DbContext to be saved to another database is extremely inefficient. Don't fall into the stereotype that "When you're a hammer, everything looks like a nail" Use the right tool for the job, not just what you happen to have in your hand at the time.